# Bind event relative to the class that created it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events, bind

Let's say I have a class laid out like so:

```
function slider() {

    this.init = function(options, title, content) {
        var self = this;
        $('body').append('<button type="button">' + title + '</button>')
    },    
    this.create = function(title, content, options) {
        var self = this;
        self.init(options, title, content);
    },
    this.closeSlider = function(elem) {
        var self = this;
        self.assignPositions();    
    },

    this.assignPositions = function() {
        alert('assign positions called from button?');
    }
}
```

To create the 'slider', I use this:

`var slider = new slider();`

Then I call the create function:

`slider.create('title', 'content');`

My question is, how can I bind the closeSlider function to the button, but it's only linked to the instance that created it? If that makes sense?

Basically, I'll have many buttons with the 'closeSlider' function, and I don't want them all to fire at once, I only want it linked to the instance that created it.

This is also a VERY trimmed down version of my class, just trying to figure this little problem out :)

Cheers

Comment: There is not value in doing `var self = this; self.assignPositions();` over `this.assignPositions()`.

Comment: consider using `$.text(title)` instead of risking treating the title as html

Comment: Wouldn't it save memory @FelixKling?

Comment: How exactly should this save memory? `self` is just an alias for `this` in that case.

Comment: I was just told that it does, as this being saved as an alias is a quicker lookup, it might be wrong but that's just what I was taught @FelixKling

Comment: Sometimes it can be faster to cache a variable from a higher scope, though I think engines will probably optimize these cases as well. Regarding `this`, since it's local and no writable, I'd argue engines could optimize that use case even better. Either way, I doubt here is any significant or measurable performance difference between those two.

Comment: I have always thought that it would use more memory as you're defining a new variable, but I wasn't going to argue with the guy who pays my bills :) @FelixKling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***bind***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on the callback function when setting the event callback

```
this.init = function(options, title, content) {
    var btn = $('<button type="button">' + title + '</button>');
    btn.click(this.closeSlider.bind(this));
    $('body').append(btn)
},
```

This will make it so when the `closeSlider` function is called it retains the context of the `slider` instance that made it. But note `this` will no longer be the context of the html element that triggered the event. So you would need to get the target from `event.target`

There might be another way of doing this without losing the context of the html element i will have to look and re-edit.

### ***Edit***

**Using event.target**

```
this.init = function(options, title, content) {
    var btn = $('<button type="button">' + title + '</button>');
    btn.click(this.closeSlider.bind(this));
    $('body').append(btn)
},  
this.closeSlider:function(event){
   //`this` will refer to slider instance
   //and event.target will be the button dom object
   var element = event.target;
});
```

**Passing the button object as an argument in `bind`**

```
this.init = function(options, title, content) {
    var btn = $('<button type="button">' + title + '</button>');
    btn.click(this.closeSlider.bind(this,btn));
    $('body').append(btn)
},  
this.closeSlider:function(btn,event){
   //`this` will refer to slider instance
   //btn will refer to the jQuery wrapped button dom object
   //event.target will still refer to the button dom object
});
```

Comment: Using jquery, is this the same equivalent? $("<button />").attr({'onclick':this.closeSlider,'type': 'button'});

Comment: @ShannonHochkins: `btn.click(...);` **is** jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/click/ . I think you should read https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: While I may have used @jSangs answer, I have accepted you because its virtually the same thing and you were first!

Comment: If I were to use this `btn.click(this.closeSlider.bind(this));` but I want to stop propagation on some items, so I ran : `btn.not('.wrapper').click(this.closeSlider.bind(this));` and then inside the closeSlider function I have event.stopPropagation() right at the top, why doesn't this work?

Comment: The event is being parsed correctly when I log it, but I'm thinking the not command is being ignored?

Comment: i don't see why you are calling `.not(".wrapper")`, `btn` only holds one element, the button. Why do you need to stopPropagation for? Is the button inside another element that needs to be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply appending a string to the body, create a live element with `document.createElement` and attach the onclick event before releasing it into the wild.

Here's an example:

```
function slider() {
    this.init = function(options, title, content) {
        var myButton = document.createElement("button");
        myButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
        myButton.innerHTML = title;
        myButton.onclick = this.closeSlider;

        $('body').append(myButton);
    },
    //Other object definitions
}
```

Comment: could I do this too? `$("<button />").attr({'onclick':this.closeSlider,'type': 'button'});`

Comment: @ShannonHochkins: No, `.attr` sets the **attribute** of the DOM element. Attribute values are **strings**.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest it. You should follow @Patrick Evans's post for the correct jQuery implementation.

Comment: that assignment to `onclick` won't work; it loses the context.

Comment: @Eevee Within the `this.init` function, isn't the context still the `slider` instance? If not I will remove my post as you are correct, this is an invalid solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should add methods onto the prototype rather than on each instance (saves memory).

Secondly, you can use jQuery's [`.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to create an anonymous function that will "hardwire" this to a particular value when it calls your method.

```
// empty constructor
function slider() 
{
}

// define prototype
$.extend(slider.prototype, {
    init: function(options, title, content) {
        $('<button>', { text: title })
            .on('click', $.proxy(this, 'closeSlider'))
            .appendTo('body');
    },
    create: function(title, content, options) {
        this.init(options, title, content);
    },
    closeSlider: function(event) {
        // event.target is the HTML element
        this.assignPositions(event.target);
    },
    assignPositions: function(elem) {
        alert('assign positions called from button?');
    }
});
```

Comment: But say I have variables inside the instance, how can I access them using a prototype?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You can declare properties on your instances that can be accessed by all methods; i.e. `this.foo = 'bar';`.

Comment: But outside of the method, as in before I was calling `var slider = new slider()`; then from there I can access all variables, example: `slider.vars.settings`

Comment: then accessing methods by slider.create();

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Right, so inside `slider.create()` you would reach them via `this.vars.settings`.

Comment: I can currently access them OUTSIDE the class though, how can you do that with prototype?

Comment: If you find it a problem that properties are accessible from "outside" the instance's functions, then a prototyped approach obviously isn't ideal.